# How do I sort a view by content type?

Tags: 7, views, search

I use a View to show search results (core Search module). In the view I have grouped the grid on the field "Content type". This works fine, each content type is shown under it's own title.

But under "Sort" in the View I can only sort the content types by ASC or DESC. But I would like to use a custom sort order like "node type = product", followed by "node type = accessories" and so on.

How to do that? I have tried using hook_views_query_alter() and hook_search_api_query_alter() and a few other tings, with no luck.

Comment: https://getlevelten.com/blog/kristin-brinner/drupal-tutorial-how-sort-search-results-content-type

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to arbitrarily order nodes, that is the use case of [Weight module](https://www.drupal.org/project/weight). The module lets you add a field to any node type with a customizable weight range. Once added to your node types, you can configure any View to use this field to sort your nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But no luck in this case. I installed the Weight module and gave my node types different weights. Then I added this wheight field to the search index and re-indexed it. I then added it as a Sort criteria in my view, with ascending order. But Views keep showing my search result in some other order. Strange... I keep looking,

Comment: Ah, views sorting is driven by search ranking. Have you looked at [`hook_ranking()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_ranking/7.x) to add your own custom weight to the index?

Comment: No matter what I do, the sorting does not do what I want :-(. I have tried the hook_ranking() too, by adding a boost to my content types in the search settings. Thanks a lot anyway for taking time to answer.